# How to evaluate all expressions in a condition?

Tags: php, lazy-evaluation

I know PHP uses lazy-evaluation / short-circuit operators. But say I wanted to evaluate all the expressions in a condition, for example:

```
$a = "Apple";
$b = "Banana";
$c = "Cherry";

function check($fruit) {
    if ($fruit != "Banana") {
        echo "$fruit is good.\n";
        return true;
    } else {
        echo "$fruit is bad.\n";
        return false;
    }
}

if (check($a) && check($b) && check($c)) {
    echo "Yummy!\n";
}
```

Because of lazy-evaluation, this will only output:

```
Apple is good.
Banana is bad.
```

Rather than the desired output of:

```
Apple is good.
Banana is bad.
Cherry is good.
```

This is useful in form validation for instance.

So my question: Is there any way to force all expressions in a condition to be evaluated in PHP, and if not, what would be the best/quickest way to get the desired result in the example above?

Comment: how about Yummy!, check a ,b or c also return true ?

Comment: in check func , $var change to  $fruit

Comment: @JOELEE Typo fixed. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [bitwise AND](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) (single ampersand: `&`)

```
$a = "Apple";
$b = "Banana";
$c = "Cherry";

function check($fruit) {
    echo ($fruit != "Banana") ? "$fruit is good.\n" : "$fruit is bad.\n";
}

if (check($a) & check($b) & check($c)) {
    echo "Yummy!\n";
}
```

Prints:

> Apple is good.
>
> Banana is bad.
>
> Cherry is good.

Example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/07092a9d6636ae8ddafce024d7cc74643e311e9c

Answer (score 0):

```
function check($fruit) {
    echo ($fruit != "Banana") ? "$fruit is good.\n" : "$fruit is bad.\n";
    return $fruit != "Banana";
}


$a = "Apple";
$b = "Banana";
$c = "Cherry";
if (check($a) & check($b) & check($c)) {
    echo "Yummy!\n";
}


/*
Apple is good.
Banana is bad.
Cherry is good.
*/


$a = "Apple";
$b = "apple";
$c = "Cherry";
if (check($a) & check($b) & check($c)) {
    echo "Yummy!\n";
}


/*
Apple is good.
apple is good.
Cherry is good.
Yummy!
*/
```